# How to style/css/specify look of result from tinyint besides 0=no 1=yes?

Tags: php

I am using this:
`<?php echo ($rad['attended']?'yes':'no'); ?>`
Any idea of the easiest way to "style" yes as green, bold text (on the website) and no to for example red, cursive text? I know how to style the text in css, but not how do I give the two alternatives different styles, can I mix inn div or something in some way inside this?

Comment: Probably `<span style="color:0f0;">yes</span>` inside condition 1. Not clear where issue is, or what has been tried yet. If that doesnt answer please provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code example, it seems that you're not using any templating system and mixing PHP with HTML. So even though it's not a good practice (to mix PHP and HTML), the easiest solution is to wrap the text in a styled `<span>`.

```
<?php
echo $rad['attended']
    ? '<span style="color: #0f0;">yes</span>' // #0f0 is green
    : '<span style="color: #f00;">no</span>'; // #f00 is red
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to do that. But there is no direct way to give a condition to CSS.

1. One approach is to give *yes* manually a style and to *no* another style

   ```
   <?php
       if($rad['attended']){
            echo '<span style="color:#4CAF50;">yes</span>';
       }else{
            echo '<span style="color:red;">no</span>';
       }
   ?>
   ```
2. Another approach can be to give a class to span in a condition before your code. And then in your CSS file you can add your text color to each class.

   ```
   <span class="
         <?php
               echo $rad['attended'] ? 'attended-green' : 'attended-red';
         ?>
   ">
   <?php echo ($rad['attended']?'yes':'no'); ?>
   </span>
   ```

There are many other approaches...

***Notice: This is not a best practice to put your view and your logic all in one file. It is always better to separate your logic and your view***